# How can one rename a connectd device in Flutter run command?

Tags: flutter, flutter-release, flutter-debug

In Flutter one can check available connected devices using `flutter devices`. When running one can do `flutter run -d <device-name>`. It turns out some devices have very long names, with numbers and letters combined. Is there a way to rename a connected device just for the current session?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways you can achieve this

1. Execute flutter run and it will display all devices in a numbered list. So all you have to do is enter a number and hit enter again
2. If your device is iohone xd45rchdjb...gjcf
   You can execute flutter run -d iphone6.. you can ignore the ID part. Also you can pass only the ID and not pass the name. That will also work